# How to pass jquery array to a laravel controller

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel

Heres my code so you can see what i'm trying to do

```
var cont = 1;
var form_data = {};
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){ //Introduce los nuevos campo
    form_data["isexo"] = $('.payment-form #sexo option:selected').text();
    form_data["icolor"] = $('.payment-form input[name="color"]').val();
    form_data["iraza"] = $('.payment-form #raza option:selected').text();
    form_data["itipo"] = $('.payment-form #tipo option:selected').text();
    form_data["iprecio"] = $('.payment-form input[name="precio"]').val();
    form_data["ipeso"] = $('.payment-form input[name="peso"]').val();
    form_data["imonto"] = parseFloat($('.payment-form input[name="precio"]').val()*$('.payment-form input[name="peso"]').val()).toFixed(2);
    form_data["remove-row"] = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>';
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $.each(form_data, function( type, value ) {
        $('<td class="input-'+type+'"><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="data-'+type+'" value="'+value+'"></td>').html(value).appendTo(row);
        cont++;
    });
    $('.preview-table > tbody:last').append(row); 
    calc_total();
    $('#sexo').val('');
    $('#color').val('');
    $('#raza').val('');
    $('#tipo').val('');
    $('#precio').val('');
    $('#peso').val('');
}); 
console.log( form_data );
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/compras/create/store",
    data: form_data
    });
```

How can i pass this array: var form_data = {} to my controller? except form_data["remove-row"]

For example: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjucJ.png)

**Update:** Trying with ajax i don't know if my code is ok,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "compras/create/store",
  data: form_data
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
      data: form_data
    });
```

My controller where $data is for return the array but:

```
public function store()
    {
        $compra = new Compra;
        $compra->fecha = Input::get('fecha');
        $compra->num_factura = Input::get('num_factura');
        $compra->id_proveedor = Input::get('proveedor');
        $compra->nombre_vendedor = Input::get('nombre_vendedor');
        $compra->total = Input::get('total');
        $compra->descuento = Input::get('desc');
        $compra->itbms = Input::get('itbms');
        $compra->total_bruto = Input::get('total_bruto');
        $id_compra = $compra->id;
        $data = Input::except('remove-row');
        if($compra->save()){
            Session::flash('message','Guardado Correctamente');
            Session::flash('class','success');
        }else{
            Session::flash('message','Ha ocurrido un error');
            Session::flash('class','danger');
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

**return:** `{"_token":"tLPlnBix0vQxkjZkHaF9cdIFPvgq7O1U7pTXye8v","fecha":"2014-11-25","num_factura":"2131AJ","proveedor":"6","nombre_vendedor":"DelPotro","id_proveedor":"","ruc":"","telef":"","sexo":"","color":"","raza":"","tipo":"","precio":"","peso":"","total_bruto":"387.00","total":"387.00","desc":"","itbms":""}` without the form_data array

Comment: What about to import the JS in the header of yur HTML?

Comment: Have you considered making an ajax call?

Comment: Use $.post or $.ajax and then pass the aavascript array to a php file

Comment: @bodruk Did you mean this: {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }} ??

Comment: @PeterKA Yes, i'm reading about that, because I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can make an ajax call to a designated route, which would in turn call a designated controller method. You can use either:

[**jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
//data: form_data,
```

Or:

[**jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

```
//with form_data as the second parameter
```

And in your controller method you can get the data using:

```
$mydata = Input::except('remove-row');
```

**NOTE**

If the element you're clicking is a `submit` button, and the ajax call is somewhere within the click handler, please consider making the following changes.

Change:

```
$('.preview-add-button').click(function(){ //Introduce los nuevos campo
        var form_data = {};
```

To:

```
$('.preview-add-button').closest('form').on('submit', function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();//this line prevents the form from submitting
        var form_data = {};
```

**UPDATE**:

In addition to the above changes, please move the ajax call so that it is as shown below:

```
    $('#peso').val('');
    console.log( form_data );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/compras/create/store",
        data: form_data,
        success: function( result ) {
            console.log( result ); //please post output of this
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What i'm doing wrong: 
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "compras/create/store",
  data: form_data
});

or

$.ajax({
      data: form_data
    });

But my controller didnt get the array

Comment: The first one looks good. Where in your jQuery code did you place this ajax call? Can you place a `console.log( form_data );` line right before making the ajax call ..... then compare the result with what's being returned.

Comment: With chrome console: icolor: "brown"imonto: "465.45"ipeso: "321"iprecio: "1.45"iraza: "jersy"isexo: "Hembra"itipo: "leche"remove-row: "<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>", the call is placed at the end of $('.preview-add-button').click(function(){ }); i renamed the form_data values to isomething for differentiate for example: form_data["icolor"]

Comment: If the page refreshes, then make the changes suggested in my answer and let us know the result.

Comment: I did the changes suggested but, with that i cant add rows and data  to form_data :(

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean. Can you provide a link to your site. See my update in a few.

Comment: This is my svn repository https://code.google.com/p/sysganado/ (here CompraController and views compra) I'm testing with laravel developer server, I'm trying to add a cattle to the buy list like this pic: http://i.imgur.com/Ppp6EcY.png, When i click on submit i should Store Fecha, No factura, proveedor, persona de contacto, total, descuento, itbms, total bruto into a table called compras ( This works fine with the controller) and store into other table called "detalle_compras" every added row with the values: sexo, color, raza, tipo , precio x kg , peso, monto all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving here the code to do the similar thing, In my case I am saving user interests ( swimming, singing, music etc) into a database table called as Interests( id, interest_name).

First Lets look at the javascript:

```js
public function saveInterests()
{
        //I declare the array here
        var allVals = [];
  
  
        //I get my values from checkboxes checked in a div with id interests  
  
        $('#interests :checked').each(function(){
       
           allVals.push($(this).val());

        });

  
        //Now I am making an post ajax call
  
        $.post("http://b2.com/saveInterests", {interests: allVals},function(data)
        {
            //this is ajax callback function
          
            if(data=='Saved')
               {
                 
                   alert('Saved With Success');
                 
               }
             else
              {
                   alert('Sorry couldnt save data in Database');
                }
         });

}
```

//A route to handle this Ajax request
Route::post('saveInterests',array('as'=>'interests.Profile','uses'=>'ProfileController@saveInterests'));

//Laravel Code in ProfileController for handling the route

```
 public function saveInterests()
{
        $iarray=Input::get('interests');  //getting my array from ajax call to Laravel
        foreach($iarray as $userInterest)
        {
            $inter = new Interest();     //creating a new row in Interest table using model
            $inter->interest_name=$userInterest;
            $inter->save();
        }
        return "Success";
 }
```